# Matrix visual how to maintain order of row value

Tags: powerbi

I have table, and using matrix visual to track some acitivity on daily basis , i want to maintain the order of journey section , how to achieve to do the same  like OTP SUBMIT , than OTP SUBMIT %, OTP VALID , OTP VALID % and so on.

[image]

I have make new column name sort key which contain key w.r.t to journey , and I am trying to sort using sort by column but unable to do the same

[image]

snapshot of data table

[image]

Comment: Do you simply want to sort a Journey column?

Comment: @intruderr yes journey column

Comment: Sure, you are doing it the right way. If you want custom order you have to create a custom column and then sort by this column. Without a custom column, you can simply click on the column in the matrix to sort.

Comment: yes , I have created the custom column but some how it was not working,  so in journey section I have added number before so it will now sort according to number  like "1. GET IT NOW", "2. OTP submit"  "3. OTP VALID", "4. Approved" , now I have make them to work , but I think  this is not a right approach ..., I have make a thing to work according to need and available time , if anyone have better solution please feel free to add it

Comment: Adding custom column and then sort Journey column by sort_key is a proper approach